# Citation inside pdfcomment gives back BibTex key

Tags: biblatex, pdfcomment

For my thesis, I am trying to add tooltips or PDF annotations to my citations, so that you don't have to go to the bibliography to check the entry. So what I want to do is add the information of the entry (roughly as it appears in the bibliography) into the tooltip or annotation. However, when I try to do this with the pdfcomment package in combination with Biblatex, all I get inside the tooltip/annotation is the Biblatex key.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Becke.1993,
        author = {Becke, Axel D.},
        year = {1993},
        title = {Density-functional thermochemistry. III. The role of exact exchange},
        pages = {5648},
        pagination = {page},
        volume = {98},
        number = {7},
        issn = {00219606},
        doi = {10.1063/1.464913},
        journal = {J. Chem. Phys.}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}
I want to add a tooltip to my references like Ref.~\cite{Becke.1993}\pdftooltip{\textsuperscript{o}}{\protect\fullcite{Becke.1993}}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As stated above, this results in "Becke.1993" being written into the tooltip, instead of "Axel D. Becke, Density-Functional ..."

Can anyone help me with a workaround on this? Thanks!

Comment: It won't work (you can't add a cite too bookmarks too), you would need an expandable cite command for this. It is not impossible to write one but it hasn't been done yet.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the quick answer! At least now I know that I don't need to spend any more time trying to make it work...

Comment: Incidentally, the build logs should've told you what Ulrike did: it says `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref)                removing '\fullcite' on input line 25.
`

Comment: A couple more comments: (i) on the technical level, the pdfcomments and pdftooltips cannot have formatting; so they are not the most ideal way to present information that may require formatting or special characters (ii) scholars of last century solved the problem you mentioned (of not wanting to flip to the end of the document), by including the citation information as either footnotes or margin notes; if an abbreviated information can be sufficiently useful, many fields use author-year citation format to partially solve this problem. Why not use one of these established conventions?

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you for the insightful comments! I will look at the alternative solutions you suggested.